# Telegram API doesnt return the full list of chats and dialogs

Tags: c#, telegram

I am using [TLSharp](http://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) and [Telegram APIs](http://core.telegram.org/methods) to work around telegram my problem is when I am trying to get my dialog list using [messages.getDialogs](http://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getDialogs) it doesnt return full list of my active dialogs it never gives the channels Ids and also it skips some other groups that I am joint in there for reasons that i dont know.

for example it returns about 20 chat IDs how ever i have about 25 groups and 15 channels but I never got the list of that chats. what is the method to get full list of dialogs including their chat_id and title?

I want to get a full list of my dialogs including channels and groups not user dialogs. I am giving this value `offset = 0` , `max_id = 0` , `limit = 100` in [messages.getDialogs](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getDialogs) method.

Comment: Following this post: https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2015/12/03/send-telegram-messages-from-c/, do you have tried this link https://api.telegram.org/botYourTokerHere/getUpdates? (you have to edit and insert your token after the word "bot" in the url)

Comment: I am not trying to send message or write a bot. i am trying to get dialog lists for my account the problem is the dialog list the API returns are incomplete without channel ids and etc

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was thinking about bots...

Comment: I could fix the channels using the `channels.getDialogs#a9d3d249 offset:int limit:int = messages.Dialogs;` but still some groups doesnt shown in returned list... :(

Comment: @EhsanHesam the idea behind offset and limit is to give you a sliding window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind offset and limit is to give you a sliding window.

You could typically start from say, offset = 0 and limit = 20 , then send another `messages.Dialogs` request with offset 20, limit = 20.

Check each time if the number of items returned each time is less than 20, then you can stop requesting.

That pattern should work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Telegram Api layer 52 (super groups and channels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801700/telegram-api-layer-52-super-groups-and-channels), Unfortunately  current non-official implementations do not support greater layers (e.g. layer 52 so they don't return channels and super groups).