# Telegram API layer 52 (super groups and channels)

Tags: schema, telegram

I am a Java developer. I found  telegram Java  API in [github](https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api), but this API is old. I want to make new library for Java (support channels and superGroups), but I can't see new layer in telegram site. The last layer in site is layer23 and it cannot support channels and superGroups. I want new layer of  [schema](https://core.telegram.org/schema/json) and JSON. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, the latest telegram layer is 54

You can always get the latest Telegram API layer from here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl

Comment: @b4hr4m you an write your own java parser based on this schema info

Comment: @b4hr4m you can search the GitHub source of the official apps. in particular, check webogram