# Telegram Latest Layer

Tags: java, schema, telegram, layer

I asked one question about telegram layer some months ago and got true answer in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801700/telegram-api-layer-52-super-groups-and-channels) , but now I have a same question because older answer is not working now.

I want updated telegram [Schema](https://core.telegram.org/schema) and [Json](https://core.telegram.org/schema/json) to updating my own library. Can anyone help me?

Comment: i need latest layer. older answer not worked because when i clicked on link , i got error >> Cyberfox can't establish a connection to the server at raw.githubusercontent.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is Telegram's latest schema which you can always get from this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/dev/Telegram/Resources/scheme.tl).

It is taken from the official Telegram Desktop repo on GitHub

The current Layer is 66

You can build your own converter to transform this file into a Telegram parser library in your preferred programming language.

Whenever the Layer changes, you simply re-run your converter and you have a TL-Parser for the latest version.

Also, you need to place the *new* and *old* TL schema side by side in a text editor that can show you the differences between the two schema (*I use a file-difference plugin for Notepad++*)

This difference shows you clearly what you need to change/include in your Telegram application to handle the changes in the new Layer.

**EDIT**

The new layer with voice calls is Layer 66: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/dev/Telegram/Resources/scheme.tl

Comment: my browser cant load this link too :)

Comment: Can you login to github? And what browser are you using?

Comment: @b4hr4m i have put it into a text tile in this gist, hopefully your browser can open this https://gist.github.com/CharlesOkwuagwu/2aeeadd89717f1f51ea8f467cef21835#file-tl-layer-62-txt

Comment: For the link in the answer I get 404 not found. But I was able to see the link with raw.... and gist...Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest layers in both `.TL` and `.JSON` format from [this](https://github.com/nimix3/TelegramSchemaLayers) repository.

Comment: The link will exist as I never delete any generally referenced links, Thank you for edit.